# Symfony2 : How create annotation route contain special characters

Tags: symfony, routes, character

In my Controller I need to create annotation route and it must be the same of this :
/getservice?from=2012-06-01&to=2012-06-25

I have tried this but it's not working

```
/**
 * @Route("/getservice",defaults={"from" = "","to" = ""})
 * @Route("/getservice?from={from}&to={to}")
 * @Template()
 */
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a route for the getservice part and get the parameters from the GET request

```
/**
 * @Route("/getservice")
 * @Template()
 */
public function getServiceAction (Request $request) {

    $from = $request->query->get('from');
    $to = $request->query->get('to');
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/getservice/{from}/{to}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function getServiceAction($from, $to){
  // ...
}
```